# How to fix UI errors after installing phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu ServerPilot app

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04, phpmyadmin

I'm following [these instructions](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/install-phpmyadmin.html), but I'm using FileZilla on Mac OS instead of Cyberduck.  I opted for installing it in my app's /public/ directory because I couldn't figure out how to access it if I installed it as its own app.

I downloaded the appropriate tar.gz and transferred it to my Ubuntu server using FileZilla but expanded it by SSHing into the server and running `tar -xvzf [filename].tar.gz`.  I then updated `$cfg['blowfish_secret']` in config.inc.php on the server as instructed.

Upon logging into phpMyAdmin I get the following error:

[image]

I tried the standard Googling and editing conf files but it won't go away.

Then the top row of menu items duplicates itself, as shown:

[image]

Clicking on anything generally has no effect.  I can get some functionality by repeatedly reloading the page and clicking on things.  I opened up the console and saw these errors increasing rapidly (several 10s of errors per second):

[image]

I'm assuming I did something wrong when I installed it.  How can I fix these errors so I can use phpMyAdmin properly?  Right now I'm trying to use MySQL terminal commands on my server and I can't really tell what's going on.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to have phpmyadmin on your server - it's just another unnecessary piece of software that will get you hacked. Instead, use Sequel Pro on your Mac, which is free, and can connect securely to your database over an SSH tunnel.

Comment: @EEAA what I couldn't do for hours using anything else I did in five minutes with Sequel Pro.  Thanks for the tip.  This solves my problem even if it doesn't directly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking EEAA's advice and simply using [Sequel Pro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) to interface with my SQL database.  It worked fine and I was up and running within a few minutes.